# Экспорт данных в pdf в WebForms

Tags: asp.net, pdf, webforms, doc

Здравствуйте!

Какие существуют компоненты, может быть, встроенные или дополнительные для экспорта данных в PDF или хотя бы в DOC из ASP.NET в Visual Studio 2010 Express?

Конечно желательно бесплатные, пусть и с ограниченным функционалом - достаточно будет экспорта таблице и картинок, ну может быть ещё таблиц.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Open Source PDF Libraries in C#](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/pdf-libraries)
- И конечно [ASP.NET FO PDF Report Server Control](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npdf/)

Comment: iTextSharp - кажется это то что нужно, спасибо - буду курить маны.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите это: [Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2005](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21916).

Comment: На сколько я знаю, Report Viewer недоступен в Express-версиях - его просто там нет, и установить его через доступные компоненты нельзя (в студии не хватает компонентов + лицензионные ограничения Express).

Comment: а в чем проблема скачать! и поставить Professional ? а если вы учитесь в университете, то у microsoft есть dreamspark (погуглите) или возьмите ключ активации в своем университете (как сделал я)

Comment: Используем Express. Была бы возможность сделать на Professional - не задавал бы вопроса.

Comment: @t1nk, `Professional` имеет *тестовый период* в течении 30 дней, + сейчас ещё можно бесплатно скачать [VS12 RC][1] от Express до Professional

[1]: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/ru-ru/downloads#vs

Comment: Спасибо конечно за информацию, но уже доделываю отчеты на [iTextSharp][1].


  [1]: http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/